# Showing an Integrable function is everywhere discontinuous

Tags: real-analysis, integration, proof-verification

> **Question**
>   Let $f(x) = x^{-1/2}$ for $0<x<1$ and $0$ otherwise, $r_n$ be an
>   enumeration of rationals. Define
>   \begin{equation}
>   g(x) = \sum_n g_n(x) \quad \text{where} \quad g_n(x) = 2^{-n}f(x-r_n)
> \end{equation}
>   Show that $g$ is discontinuous everywhere.

**Attempt**
I claim $g$ is unbounded for any interval $I$, which
  implies it cannot be continuous anywhere. Note that if $(x-r_n) \leq 2^{-2n}$
  then $g_n(x) \geq 1$. Construction relies on the fact that
  any interval contains infinitely many $r_n$.

For $I$, there exists $r_k\in I$ with a corresponding interval $I_k
  \subset I$ of size $2^{-2k}$ with left endpoint $r_k$. Repeat for
  $I_k$, there exists $r_{k'}\in I_k$ with a corresponding interval
  $I_{k'}\subset I_k$ of size $2^{-2k'}$ with left end point $r_{k'}$. 
  Therefore, there exists an increasing sequence of $r_k$'s
  and they converge, say to $x$. Note that $(x - r_k) \leq 2^{-2k}$
  for all $k$ in this construction. It follows, $g(x) = \sum_n g_n(x)
  \geq \sum_k g_k(x) \geq \sum_k 1= \infty$.

Appreciate if one can verify/point out the mistake/suggest another approach. Notation is not very precise, but hopefully explains it.

Comment: I just wanted to comment that your interval $I$ should be closed. Certainly $f(x)=x$ is unbounded on $\mathbb{R}$, but it’s continuous everywhere.

Comment: Why would $g$ be unbounded? Note that $|f(x)|\leq 1$ for all $x$. So $|g_n(x)|\leq 2^{-n}$ meaning $|g(x)|\leq \sum\limits_n 2^{-n}=1$

Comment: @J.Pistachio: $|f(x)|\le 1$ would be the case if $f(x)$ was $x^{1/2}$, but it is $x^{-1/2}$.

Comment: Ah, didn't see the negative. Sorry about that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently the codomain of $g$ includes $\infty$. That can in itself be okay; there are good topologies on the extended real line.

Your argument seems to lead to the the fact that there is a dense set of points $x$ where $g(x)=\infty$. However, that in itself does not make $g$ discontinuous everywhere -- as far as you have argued so far, there might be an entire interval somewhere where $g(x)=\infty$. Then $g$ would be perfectly continuous in the interior of such interval.

So you need an explicit argument that this is not the case. (One is suggested by the *title* of your question, but you should write it down explicitly ...)